# Launch jar with custom command line program

Tags: java, command-line, executable

Suppose I have some folder in a directory:

```
- MyApp
  - lib
    - myapp.jar
```

The location of the `MyApp` directory is supposed to be stored in an environment variable, like `APP_HOME`. I would like to add a `bin` folder that contains two commmand-line executables that launch the java program, one for Windows and one for Unix-based OSs. I already know that one file would just be called `myapp` and modified with `chmod +x`, and the Windows one would be named `myapp.bat`.

What I am unsure about is what the contents of these files would be. As said, both would run the jar file with a custom command line command whose arguments are passed to the `main` method, as shown below:

```
>myapp -debug key=value moreargs...
```

***EDIT***: How would I go about creating this environment variable, from Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass command line arguments to the executable by adding `$*` at the end of the command in the Unix shell script, and `%*` for the Windows batch file:

```
java -jar $APP_HOME/lib/myapp.jar $*
```

Comment: Can you also see my edit about the environment variable?